# How to run/debug local code using remote interpreter in Pycharm?

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, remote-debugging

I followed below instructions to setup remote interpreter and remote deployment.

https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/work-remotely-with-pycharm-tensorflow-and-ssh-c60564be862d

It says the below

> Deployment
>
> The remote interpreter can not execute a local file, PyCharm have to
> copy your source files (your project) to a destination folder on your
> remote server, but this will be done automatically and you don’t need
> to think about it!

However, I even after setting up automatic deployment in Tools|Deployment|Automatic Upload(always). It is not working as expected and not syncing up files between remote and local automatically in a seamless manner.

**Question**

So how can I just skip deployment and sync between remote and local folder all together and just run/debug my local code using remote interpreter?

I mean on a local .py file i should be able to but a breakpoint and debug using remote interpreter? This makes life more easier and not worry about sync.